# What are good risk management books or docs?

Tags: risk-management, derivatives, reference-request, books

I have an unusual request/question. I was wondering if anyone here could recommend me some books about risk management and equity derivatives.

I am about to do an internship as a risk analyst on an Equity derivatives desk and I am looking for any book, resources that could prepare me for the job

Comment: What is your current level of knowledge? Risk management of equity derivatives mainly uses "greeks": variables called Delta, Gamma, Theta, etc. Do you know or have you heard of these before? Have you studied Black Scholes Merton model?

Comment: Hi noob2 thanks a lot for the swift reply. I would need something quite "advanced" since I have seen BSM model, and derivatives at school (I have had classes about stochastic calculus as well)

Comment: Then maybe... just relax and enjoy your internship and interact with new people in a new context... ;)

Comment: This [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33132/what-are-the-books-in-which-to-study-the-basics-of-the-derivative-financial-inst) could be already answering to your needs. If you're looking for something more advanced, write another question referring to the other one and pointing out which topics were missing.

Comment: I doubt this question is a duplicate: He is asking about risk management books and not pricing ones -- these are separate concepts (there is obviously some intersection but they are not identical). Anyway, since you have some BSM exposure, I would go for this one if I were you: [link](https://www.amazon.com/Financial-Management-Dummies-Aaron-Brown/dp/111908220X/ref=pd_cp_14_3/141-0182525-2623352?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=J4N2V67WNXQY3CCAZ00D)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that 'Derivatives Markets' by McDonald and 'Options Futures and other Derivatives' by Hull are both good books if you want to refresh your memory.